# how defined file permission downloaded image for only visible for my app In phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am writing a phonegap application for android.I downloaded an image from internet and then save to phone local storage.Images are showing in photo gallery,and users can access this image from other application ( example file manager).

I want to show this image only on my app.I want to define this image ,can't read other application and don't want to show photo gallery.

How can I write? please anyone help me.
thank.
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: How about removing file extension (eg. .jpg, .png etc.)? The file will become unreadable to all file manager and gallery apps unless user manually applies an extension to file.

Comment: thank for your comment,Now I will test as you say.

Comment: @ashu,It work as you say,I already tested.thank for your comment,your comment should be accepted answer,but the images (downloaded without file extensions) can be viewed at computer.